# Convert an arbitrary in place operator to a unary operator in C++

Tags: c++, functor

`std::transform()` takes a unary operator which operates on some type T. It should look like `T f(T&)`. Sometimes we work with a function that isn't suitable like `boost::algorithm::to_lower()` which returns void and is of a type that takes more than one argument (though the others are default). I can convert `boost::algorithm::to_lower()` like so

```
struct tl {
    template<typename T>
    T operator()(T &v) const { 
        boost::algorithm::to_lower(v);
        return v;
    }
};
```

and use this

```
tl  low;
std::vector<...> vec;
...
std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), low);
```

What I'd like to do is generalize this one step further; let `f()` be a function taking one parameter of type `T&` and possibly multiple other parameters which necessarily have default values and returning an arbitrary type (could be T, could be void, could be something else, we just assume it acts on the referenc value passed. Further `f` itself may be template as boost::algorithm::to_lower() is. I would like to do something that one might expect to

```
tl<decltype f>  low(f);
```

to do then be able to call

```
std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), low);
```

so that I'm not writing a class for each function I want to convert. Obviously decltype(f) doesn't work here. C++11 is preferred but if 14 or 17 is necessary that's okay.

Comment: The current behaviour of this is dangerous if you transform into a container that's different than the source one.  For example: `transform(begin(vec1), end(vec1), begin(vec2), low);` will output the modified sequence into `vec2` but `vec1` will also be modified, which is usually unexpected.  Why not just use `for_each` in this case?

Comment: Why not use a lambda?

Comment: What's wrong with `std:for_each` ?

Comment: And then you call `const char* src = "hello";` `char dst[8];` `std::transform(src, src + 6, dst, low);` and your program crashes ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following macro:

```
#define MAKE_FUNCTIONAL( f ) []( auto x ){ f(x); return x; }
```

You can use it like that:

```
std::transform( vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), 
                MAKE_FUNCTIONAL(boost::algorithm::to_lower) );
```

That'll work like a charm. :)  This requires C++14 since it uses a lambda with an auto parameter.

Comment: Yeah, since function templates are not first class citizens your only option to do this is with a macro.  I still disapprove of taking the parameter by reference as per my comment above unless it's intended to be used with `for_each` instead.

Comment: @GuyGreer Agreed. I'll remove the references from the parameter type. The thing is now fixed and should work as expected.